# No response when request takes 5 minutes or longer

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient

I have encountered a very strange issue - HttpClient's SendAsync never returns when request to the specific web server takes 5 minutes or longer.

This is a sample WebApi controller method that I try to get the response from

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Entity/Ping")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Ping([FromUri] int time)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(time));
            var bytes = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)42, 100_000_000).ToArray();

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "result.bin";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

            return response;
        }
```

And this is a code for sending a request

```
            using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(handler))
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                var url = "http://problem-server/WebApp/api/Entity/Ping?time=5";
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = new Uri(url)
                };
                var response = await client.SendAsync(
                    request,
                    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                    default);

                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    return stream;

                return default;
            }
```

As you can see, everything is pretty simple and should work without issues. But it doesn't and SendAsync call just hangs forever (for 10 minutes).
In the same time it works when [time] parameter is less then 5.
Additionally, when you open the URL in a browser it successfully downloads a result.bin file after 5 minutes of processing, so method works.

Firstly I thought this is due to a deadlock.
But synchronous request using old WebRequest class to the same URL also hangs

```
            var url = "http://problem-server/WebApp/api/Entity/Ping?time=5";
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds;
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (stream != null)
                return stream;

            return default;
```

Next, I copied the WebApp folder to another server, lets call it ok-server.
Modified the URLs in http client and web request methods.
And, magically, everything works - the response is received after [time] minutes.

So the issue is with the problem-server.
But how to debug \ investigate it - IIS request tracing or logs "say" that the request has completed successfully after [time] minutes and the response was sent.

Both machines, problem-server and ok-server, have IIS 8.5 and Windows Server 2012 R2.
Web Api uses .NET Framework 4.5.
(I have also tried to use .NET Core 3.1 with ASP.NET Core hosted on IIS for the Web Api - the result is the same)

Can you help me find the reason for this issue?
Perhaps, I need to look into global machine configs or maybe network setting.

I am truly lost right now.

UPDATE

problem_server and ok_server are in different network segments.
problem_server IP is 192.168.114.100 and ok_server IP is 192.150.0.15.
To diagnose possible network misconfigurations I decided to send a request to the problem_server from the machine in its IP segment.
Here is the result when executing the test client from 192.168.114.125 machine
[image: Successful request]

My workstation is yet in another IP segment - 192.135.9/24. Perhaps there are some router settings between 192.150.0/24 and 192.135.9/24 segments that allow the request to the ok_server to succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really recommend that you not execute a five minute delay in your API controller. It will give you more grief than it's worth. For example, when IIS restarts your AppPool, it will wait up to 90 seconds for requests to process. During these autonomous restarts, this request will be aborted.

The problem server may have TCP KeepAlive set to Microsoft's recommended (but not default) value of 5 minutes. Because the HttpClient doesn't implement TCP keepalives by default, the problem server OS is likely disconnecting the TCP socket before the response is sent to the client because the client fails to respond to the keepalive being sent by the problem server OS.

You could adjust the TCP KeepAlive setting at the OS level on the problem server by editing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ subkey as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc739819(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Alternatively, you can configure the client to support TCP keepalive before sending the request by [configuring the ServicePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.settcpkeepalive?view=net-6.0#system-net-servicepoint-settcpkeepalive(system-boolean-system-int32-system-int32)).  If there is a network device, such as a stateful firewall, between the client and server, a high frequency keep-alive setting may help keep the connection open.

```
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(url));
 sp.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 6000, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to set KeepAlive using ServicePointManager but it had no effect.

Comment: If you run a packet capture on both machines, do you see the response traffic on both? Can you run the client code directly on the problem server? Those tests may give more insight.

Comment: Yes, I can run the client code directly on the problem server. And everything works - response is received after 5 minutes. I have asked system administrators to capture the traffic during request execution.

Comment: There may be a firewall that is marking the socket as stale and then not allowing the response traffic because there is no existing connection in the eyes of the firewall. 
 Try setting keepalive to a really low value to see if this will help the network device keep the socket marked active.

sp.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 6000, 3000);

Comment: WOW. It worked. Will talk with sys admins about this finding. Thanks